# How to access the integer value from an Integer object in Android

Tags: android, charts, integer

I'm trying to add data (floats specifically) to a bar chart I'm creating with [achartengine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/). I've created a HashMap to hold keys/values but I'm not able to access the actual value of the Integer (i.e., Integer.valueOf). See below:

```
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getBarDemoDataset() {
       XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
       HashMap<String, Integer> myMap = AppStatus.mDayMap;
       Iterator it = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
       for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
          CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Demo series " + (i + 1));
          while(it.hasNext()){
             Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
             // I should be able to code pairs.getValue().valueOf() but I get an error - the value seems to be a string below.
             series.add((Double)pairs.getValue()); 
          }

      dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
   }
   return dataset;
}
```

Comment: Why does the comment say "string"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Integer i = 42;
double d = i.doubleValue();
```

So:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
    series.add(entry.getValue().doubleValue()); 
}
```

Although I would have thought that a series chart should be ordered, which would not be the case when iterating over a `HashMap`.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! Here's what I added: series.add(((Integer) pairs.getValue()).doubleValue()); I think you're right about the series chart. Thanks for bringing that to my attention as well!

Comment: @user836200 No problem. You could use a `LinkedHashMap`, which preserves insertion order, if you need that, or just use a list.

Answer (score 1):

**Solving the compilation issue**

By error I assume you mean the compilation error resulting from trying to cast an Integer to a Double... Such type conversion between numerics only works automatically with primitive types.

Changing

```
series.add((Double)pairs.getValue());
```

to

```
series.add(new Double(pairs.getValue()));
```

solves the compilation issue.

**On the use of valueOf()**

`valueOf()` is used primarily to convert String values to a numeric type.  The overloaded version of the form:

```
Double.valueOf(double d)
```

is a holdover from the days before autoboxing.  Since your data (the value side of the Map entry) is already numeric, there is no need to use `valueOf()` in this context.

Comment: FWIW, `CategorySeries.add()` actually takes a `double`, so getting the `doubleValue` of the existing `Integer` is likely quicker than instantiating a new `Double` which is then primitivized.